# How to solve the following ODE's with initial conditions symbolically

Tags: differential-equations

How would I solve these ODE's both with initial conditions $I(t)=I_0$

$$\frac{d I}{dt} = \beta I - \frac{\beta I^2}{N} \qquad (1)$$

and

$$\frac{d I}{dt} = (\beta-\gamma) I - \frac{\beta I^2}{N} \qquad (2)$$

A solution was given to the second ODE on a paper but I don't know how they got it:

$$
I(t)=
\frac{\left(\beta-\gamma\right)NI_0}
     {\left(\beta-\gamma\right)N
         e^{-\left(\beta-\gamma\right)t}
     +\beta I_0 \left[1-
         e^{-\left(\beta-\gamma\right)t}
       \right]
     }
$$

Thank you.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk thank you, really appreciated! Maybe you should post that as an answer so I can give you best answer :)

Comment: Both are versions of the [logistic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function#In_ecology:_modeling_population_growth), which is solvable as a [Bernoulli differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_differential_equation) / [Riccati equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation).

Comment: And to state what is probably obvious, the first equation is the special case of the second when $\gamma=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DSolve[{i'[t] == (β - γ)*i[t] - β i[t]^2/n,i[0] == I0}, i[t], t] // FullSimplify
```

Comment: Can you plot this solution?