# Solving a non-linear system of equations symbolically

Tags: equation-solving, symbolic, nonlinear, system

How would I solve this systems of non-linear equations symbolically:

$$
\mu N -\frac{\beta S I}{N} - \nu S = 0 \qquad (1)$$

$$\frac{\beta S I}{N} -\gamma I - \nu I = 0 \qquad (2)$$

$$\gamma I - \nu R = 0 \qquad (3)
$$

where $S+I+R=N$ and $\mu, \beta, \nu,\gamma >0$

EDIT:

```
Solve[u*n - (b/n)*p*s - v*s = 
  0 && (b/n)*p*s - g*p - v*p = 0 && g*p - v*r = 0 {s, p, r}, 
 n = s + p + r]
```

EDIT II:

How would I find the solution to this system:

$$
-\frac{\beta S I}{N} =0  \qquad (1)$$

$$\frac{\beta S I}{N} -\gamma I=0   \qquad (2)$$

$$\gamma I=0   \qquad (3)
$$

where $S+I+R=N$ and $\beta,\gamma >0$.

I have these as the solutions;

$$(S^*,I^*,R^*) = (K, 0, N-K),$$
for any $0\leq K \leq N$.

Comment: Please provide Mathematica code. Which are the unknowns? It's not recommended to use `N` and `I` as variable names

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I am new to Mathematica so I don't have a code. Unknowns are S,I,R

Comment: Look into `Solve` and `NSolve`, with `FindRoot` as a numerical backup plan in case those don't work.

Comment: @ChrisK I tried "Solve" but its giving me a trivial answer. maybe I've typed it incorrectly but I don't know..

Comment: You don't have a code,but you tried `Solve` ?

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk I tried after Chris suggested. I'll edit it.

Comment: `Solve[{n == s + p + r, 
  u*n - (b/n)*p*s - v*s == 0, (b/n)*p*s - g*p - v*p == 0, 
  g*p - v*r == 0}, {s, p, r}, MaxExtraConditions -> All]` works fine for me.

Comment: Syntax issue. `Equal` in infix is `==`, not `=`. That latter is infix for `Set` (as in "set lhs to value on rhs").

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk I tried your solution but I don't get clear solutions. We should have 2 solutions; 1) trivial solution (N,0,0) and 2) a "longer" solution. how do I simplify your input to get these two solutions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An improved solution  based on  @MariuszIwaniuk straightforward comment follows with `MaxExtraConditions ->  Automatic`

```
sol = Solve[{n == s + p + r,u*n - (b/n)*p*s - v*s == 0, (b/n)*p*s - g*p - v*p == 0,g*p - v*r == 0}
, {s, p, r } ,MaxExtraConditions ->   Automatic ]
(*{
{s -> ConditionalExpression[n, u == v],
p -> ConditionalExpression[0, u == v], 
r -> ConditionalExpression[0, u == v]}
,
{s ->ConditionalExpression[(n (g + v))/b, u == v],
p -> ConditionalExpression[(v (n - (n (g + v))/b))/(g + v), u == v],
r -> ConditionalExpression[n - (n (g + v))/b - (v (n - (n (g + v))/b))/(g + v), u == v]}
}*)
```

Comment: Why do I get the following when I use your input in Mathematica? "Solve[{True, -((b p s)/(p + r + s)) + (p + r + s) u - s v == 
   0, -g p + (b p s)/(p + r + s) - p v == 0, g p - r v == 0}, {s, p, 
  r}, MaxExtraConditions -> {Automatic}]"

Comment: Try to restart your kernel! I modified my answer and removed curly brackets in `MaxExtraConditions ->   Automatic `

Comment: aha! now it doesn't show solutions for "s"...

Comment: Code runs as shown in my answer(with fresh kernel). My Mathematicaversion is 12.2 Windows 64

Comment: I'm using 11.1 Mathematica windows 10 but I don't know what's wrong...

Comment: Show your solution "without s", perhaps s is already definde?

Comment: what a surprise, it decides to show up when you ask after running it 100 times :)

Comment: Hi again, I am doing a more complicated model and I have the solutions, but how do I put them in terms of $R_0$? so for the system I posted in the original question, how would I implement in the Mathematica that I want solutions in terms of $R_0 = \beta/ (\gamma + \nu)$?

Comment: I'm not sure if I got your question. Perhaps substitution `b->R0 (n+g)`

Comment: We have solutions for $S, I, R$, as per your answer. Now, I want them in terms of $R_0$. for example; $S= n(\gamma+\nu)/\beta = n/R_0$. How would I do this for all solutions for all models that I consider?

Comment: This is what I mean for clarity: 
$$ e_1 : \left( S_1^*, I_1^*, R_1^*\right)= \left(N, 0, 0\right), \\
e_2 : \left( S_2^*, I_2^*, R_2^*\right)= \left(\frac{N \gamma}{\beta}, \frac{N\xi}{\gamma + \xi}\left(1-\frac{\gamma}{\beta}\right), \frac{N\gamma}{\gamma + \xi}\left(1-\frac{\gamma}{\beta}\right)\right)\\ =\left(\frac{N}{\mathcal{R}_0}, \frac{aN}{\mathcal{R}_0}\left(\mathcal{R}_0-1\right),\frac{bN}{\mathcal{R}_0}\left(\mathcal{R}_0-1\right) \right)
$$

where $a = \xi/\left(\gamma +\xi\right)$ and $b = \gamma/\left(\gamma +\xi\right)$.

Comment: what if I don't want $u=v$?

Comment: You try to solve 4 equations for 3 unknowns. Mathematica shows the conditions that solution exists. In your case solution requires `u==v`,  there is no choice.

Comment: can you take a look at the following question? the solution is provided but how can I plot the solution? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/240876/how-to-solve-the-following-odes-with-initial-conditions-symbolically

Comment: If the parameters are defined try `sol=DSolve[{i'[t] == (β - γ)*i[t] - β i[t]^2/n,i[0] == I0}, i[t], t]; Plot[Evaluate[i[t] /. sol[[1]] /. para ], {t, 0, 10}]`

Answer (score 1):

```
eq1 = mu *NN - beta*(SS*II)/NN - v *SS == 0;
eq2 = beta*(SS*II)/NN - gama*II - v*II == 0;
eq3 = gama*II - v*RR == 0;
eq4 = SS + II + RR == NN;
sol = Solve[{eq1, eq2, eq3}, {SS, II, RR}]
```

[image]

Note that the solutions should satisfy `eq4` with given parameters.

Comment: Shouldn't SS be equal to N?

Comment: @Math: Birth rate `mu` is assumed to be equal to the death rate `v`. Since these are two given parameters, they do not have to be equal in fact. But your formulation of the problem gives `SS=(mu/v)*NN` if `II=0 and RR=0` (first solution).

Comment: This is understood. we have assumed $\mu = \nu$. but your solution omits the "$N$" in the first solution part which is why I was wondering. maybe a typo!

Comment: @Math as Tugrul indicates, this solution is normalized such that `NN=1`, this is why it is “missing” from the first solution part as you observed. If `mu/v` is unitless as it should be, and it is scaled to `NN=1`, then to have the appropriate units as SS, it must be that `(mu/v)*NN==SS` and this is true because `NN=1`.

Comment: @Math: The formal symbolic solution includes `NN` but I dropped it because `NN=1` is assumed. @CA Trevillian's explanation is right.

Comment: @TugrulTemel could you put it back in solely for formal reasons

Comment: @TugrulTemel sorry i made a typo, it should be $\gamma I - \nu R$. then your solution works as desired :)

Comment: @Math: I revised the `code` and gave the full format of the MMA output. I am using MMA version 11.3 and have no problem with solving the problem.

Comment: @TugrulTemel: Yes, I got the correct solution. Thank you very much for helping me :)

Comment: @Math: Your welcome...

Comment: @TugrulTemel I need to solve the easier problem, I will edit in the question. Can you tell me your solution so I can cross-check whether mine and yours match.

Comment: @Math: In your edited version, `I=0` implies `R=0` which in turn implies that `S=N`. The solution is then `(S,I,R)=(N,0,0)`. This is a trivial solution because from `gama*I=0` we see that `I=0`.

Comment: @TugrulTemel Aha yes. So regardless of the reproduction number, $R_0 =\beta/\gamma$ for this model, it will always tend to our trivial equilibria?

Comment: @Math: Reproduction is relevant if there is at least one person infected initially. If nobody is infected `(S,I,R) = (N,0,0)`, which is the case in your trivial formulation, the reproduction rate `R0` is irrelevant.

Comment: @TugrulTemel yes, in all formulations, we assume $I(0)=i_0$

Comment: @Math: Your equation (3) above is telling us that `I=0` because the parameter `gama` (recovery rate) is positive. I think we need to look at what the equations are telling us, not what we are thinking.